# Can I create a network conflict with my router?

Tags: networking, routing

I moved to a new office (private office in a cowork space with no network guys at all) and I brought my own router to plug into the existing network.

The DHCP address range for the current network is:

> 192.168.0.100 to 255

I plugged my router and configured to use router IP

> 192.168.5.1

It is set in DHCP mode so I'm in a different subnetwork.

Can this cause a network conflict? This morning they were blaming me for the issue that a couple of machine next to me did not have network connectivity.

### EDIT

I plugged the RJ45 cable to the WAN port of my router and let the office DHCP assign an IP after properly setting up my subnetwork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are plugged into the same wiring, yes, two DHCP servers will wreak havok. What likely happened is the machines they were having an issue with picked up an IP from your router, and access was lost to their original network resources.

To avoid dual DHCP servers, you would need to plug their LAN into the "Internet" or WAN port on the router, and your gear goes on the LAN side of your router.

EDIT: If you are plugged from their LAN into the WAN port of your router, you should not see this. The last thing would be wireless. If this device also broadcasts, is it possible their machines picked it up and connected?

Comment: I need to be behind my own router since I have a couple of ESXI servers that need to fix the IP. I already configured IP and routing tables and the guys here are not network admins at all (pretty small office actually)

Comment: The office DHCP is giving my router a WAN ip of 192.168.0.136. How can someone else get that IP to conflict with my subnetwork?

Comment: Exactly what I did, people managing the office with their own pretty basic home router are not computer guys at all. I'm the most capable here (fortunately), but want to make sure I do not "wreck havoc".

Comment: @code-gijoe My advice: ***STOP***. Touch nothing (and connect no devices to this network) until you have located the person responsible for the environment. Explain what you need, and ask the responsible person to provide it. If in your search you discover there is no responsible person, you now have a job opportunity (assume responsibility for the network, document it, and then you will know what you can and cannot do while preserving the integrity of the network for all other users), or a case for a professional consultant.

Comment: @voretaq7. I did talk to guy in charge, he doesn't even know how to access his own router. But, in the real world of startups I need to fix this myself with whatever resources I have, so I came to serverfault.

Comment: @code-gijoe Then you need to replace the guy in charge with someone competent (possibly you?) -- In the *real world* of enterprise IT if I found someone plugging a SoHo router into my network I would smash the device to bits with the bat I keep in my closet. Rogue devices like that cause major problems (from outages to security breaches) and the network admin is the one who has to deal with things when the fecal matter hits the rotary air distribution device.

Comment: @voretaq7, I cannot come at a new office of about 20 people and tell them how poor their job is. They have a SOHO Linksys router and in due time they'll hopefully go for some better equipment. I used to work at a huge company and met people with bats like you but that is not the case for most small and medium-sized businesses.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using some sort of cheap SOHO router. In this case you must plug its WAN port into the office network, and no other ports.

Comment: This is an private office in a cowork space, so yes, it's cheap. I did plus my router into it's wan port.

Comment: BTW, I do have some old but pretty expensive gear from back where we had our own private offices :)